# Google Line Chart: How to change decimal mark in tooltips?

Tags: google-visualization

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Example

How can I change the decimal mark in the tooltips from period to comma?

Comment: The tooltips do not currently contain any periods?

Comment: Not in the example, you're right. But if you write "1000.0" instead of "1000", they do.

Answer (score 0):

Google Charts use a subset of the [ICU DecimalFormat Class](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details). Unfortunately, that subset does not include the ability to change locales to the best of my knowledge. If you do want to try, you can try a version of this javascript using a locale (such as Europe) which uses commas as decimal separators (this prints out all locale information, so you'll have to dig through the reference to figure out how to set a single locale first):

```
// Normally we would have a GUI with a menu for this
int32_t locCount;
const Locale* locales = NumberFormat::getAvailableLocales(locCount);
double myNumber = -1234.56;
UErrorCode success = U_ZERO_ERROR;
NumberFormat* form;
// Print out a number with the localized number, currency and percent
// format for each locale.
UnicodeString countryName;
UnicodeString displayName;
UnicodeString str;
UnicodeString pattern;
Formattable fmtable;
for (int32_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
  cout << endl << "FORMAT " << j << endl;
  for (int32_t i = 0; i < locCount; ++i) {
    if (locales[i].getCountry(countryName).size() == 0) {
      // skip language-only
      continue;
    }
    switch (j) {
      case 0:
        form = NumberFormat::createInstance(locales[i], success ); break;
      case 1:
        form = NumberFormat::createCurrencyInstance(locales[i], success ); break;
      default:
        form = NumberFormat::createPercentInstance(locales[i], success ); break;
    }
    if (form) {
      str.remove();
      pattern = ((DecimalFormat*)form)->toPattern(pattern);
      cout << locales[i].getDisplayName(displayName) << ": " << pattern;
      cout << " -> " << form->format(myNumber,str) << endl;
      form->parse(form->format(myNumber,str), fmtable, success);
      delete form;
    }
  }
}
```